# following copy and paste code does not function, showing runtime error 1004

Tags: object, runtime

The following code has been created by following directions, I as trying to copy from a data sheet to an audit sheet but am shon the following error Runtime error 1004

Sub copy_data_to_EditNFormat()

```
Dim count_col As Integer
Dim count_row As Integer
Dim check_header As Integer
Dim orig As Worksheet
Dim output As Worksheet
Dim position As Integer


Set orig = Sheet2
Set output = Sheet15

'count number of rows of data on sheet2
output.Activate
check_header = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1"), Range("A4").End(xlDown))

'count the number of rows of data on sheet1
orig.Activate
count_col = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1"), Range("A4").End(xlRight))
count_row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A1"), Range("A4").End(xlDown))

'filter data on sheet1 based on criertia in G3
ActiveSheet("A4").AutoFilter field:=2, criteria:=Cells(2, 6).Value


position = 4

If check_header > 0 Then

End If


orig.Range(Cells(pos, 1), Cells(count_row, count_col)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
output.Cells(check_header + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
appliaction.CutCopyMode = False
orig.ShowAllData
orig.AutoFilterMode = False
output.Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
```

End Sub

Comment: I think we need more information. What line is causing the error? What are the values of the variables when the error happens? There are several kinds of 1004 errors, is any more context given with the error? Etc. I encourage you to manually walk through your code, because there are couple of things you're doing that don't make sense. Finally, It might help if we understood the data in the spreadsheet a little better.